# GlusterFS failed on Mount

Tags: persistence, cluster-computing, glusterfs

I'm trying to install and configure GlusterFS for a phisical cluster.

I did the steps of the link below, but when I try, the mount failed.

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/high-availability-storage-with-glusterfs-on-ubuntu-1804

Volume Info:

```
# gluster volume info vol01

Volume Name: vol01
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: f6def2b8-24c5-41c8-bf1b-f8396bbac90a
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 192.168.100.104:/mnt/glusterfs
Brick2: 192.168.100.106:/mnt/glusterfs
Options Reconfigured:
performance.client-io-threads: off
nfs.disable: on
transport.address-family: inet
```

Status:

```
# gluster volume status
Status of volume: vol01
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick 192.168.100.104:/mnt/glusterfs        49152     0          Y       2085 
Brick 192.168.100.106:/mnt/glusterfs        49152     0          Y       2061 
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       1857 
Self-heal Daemon on 192.168.100.106         N/A       N/A        Y       1795 

Task Status of Volume vol01
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

Log of the client:

```
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.275690] I [glusterfsd.c:1910:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.4.2 (/usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-id=/mnt/glusterfs --volfile-server=tesla /mnt/glusterfs)
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.280052] I [socket.c:3480:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: SSL support is NOT enabled
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.280116] I [socket.c:3495:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: using system polling thread
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.284558] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1574:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.284591] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1674:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:/mnt/glusterfs)
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.285217] W [glusterfsd.c:1002:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0x105) [0x7f80043bbe15] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_handle_reply+0x90) [0x7f80043bbc10] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(mgmt_getspec_cbk+0x449) [0x7f8004a72d09]))) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
[2018-09-21 21:11:09.285241] I [fuse-bridge.c:5260:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/mnt/glusterfs'.
```

Comment: How is this related to Kubernetes?

Comment: What command are you using to mount `gluster` volume to a host?

Comment: sudo mount -t glusterfs 192.168.100.104:/vol01 /mnt/glusterfs

Comment: @Rico I did the same thing on kubernetes, deploying an glusterfs server with this tool but I've got the same problem.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito According to log you are using glusterfs client version `3.4.2` which is very outdated. Have you installed gluster server version `3.12` how it is described in documentation? Issue could be here. Please try to update your glusterfs client.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue today, I have ssl enabled for clients and servers. In my case I had not set the secure-access option on the client (making it use the glusterfs.ca file in /etc/ssl/)

To solve do this:

```
touch /var/lib/glusterd/secure-access
```

Comment: I still ran into the same issue